# firstdayofpreviousmonth and firstdayofcurrent month for @startDate and @EndDate parameter DAX code

Tags: sql, azure, powerbi, dax

I'm working in PowerBi I am trying to automate the following code. (Using Azure SQL Database data)

```
Table = Reporting_PremiumBDX_QBEPremiumSL("QBE%", @StartDate(yyyy,mm,d), @EndDate(yyyy,mm,d))
```

I need the @startdate = FirstDayOfPreviousMonth and @endDate=Firstdayofcurrentmonth. I'm new to DAX so I'm having trouble with the formatting.

The SQL query that I run to produce the same data is

```
select * from Reporting.PremiumBDX_QBEPremiumSL('QBE%', 11/1/2023, 12/1/2023)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need the @startdate = FirstDayOfPreviousMonth and @endDate=Firstdayofcurrentmonth.

As per this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/startofmonth-function-dax) You can use `STARTOFMONTH` function in DAX quety to get the first date of the month in the current context.

**Sample example:**

```
startdate =  STARTOFMONTH(TODAY())
enddate = STARTOFMONTH(DATEADD(TODAY(),-1,Month)) 

--Sample Querywill look like:

Table = Reporting_PremiumBDX_QBEPremiumSL("QBE%", STARTOFMONTH(TODAY()), STARTOFMONTH(DATEADD(TODAY(),-1,Month)))
```